# Trifacta, upload Recipe output to existing SharePoint list

Tags: sharepoint, trifacta

I'm using Trifacta (8.7 I think) and I need to upload the output of a recipe to an existing SharePoint list, but I'm not seeing where I define which column in my output goes to the column in the SharePoint list.  I'm hoping I don't have to match by position as an append and have an input for every column (even if NULL), but I fear that may be the case.
Anyone know the answer to this?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  Unlike, say, SSIS where you designate which source column populates which destination column, Trifacta asks the user to change the name of the column of the source in the Recipe (those that use Trifacta understand what the means) to match the destination SharePoint list.  Add a Recipe step that changes the names of the columns to match the column names in your SharePoint list.  In addition, beware of both data type and/or constraints that have been added to the SharePoint list that can fail your run if the data doesn't match.
Please note that Trifacta 8.x versions only see raw SharePoint lists, not views of the list that have been created.